# Rebirth Pertaining to Religion

Tags: rebirth

I'm curious to know if throughout my rebirths I have stayed the same religion, race, etc. or if I was of a different classification? I wonder this because Hinduism is an all-embracing religion and so it is not necessary for one to be Hindu to be graced and/or blessed by God? I am Hindu myself and would never change that, but I really do wonder if/how identities that are derived from social constructs traverse through all of the rebirths? I thought only our soul travels through rebirths.

Comment: related : http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2886/how-does-karma-work-for-a-person-who-has-converted-to-hinduism

Comment: hinduism is something like universal law. it applies to every  energy in the universe. religions were constructed by humans.there is nothing like hindu and non-hindu. karma applies to every living and non living things.

Comment: There is a book called 'Bhrigu Samhita' which was written by Maharishi Bhrigu. This book contains the details about every person's past, present and future births based on his astrological chart. But, most portion of the book is now destroyed/lost. You can find the details about this book in my answer [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3807/what-is-actually-there-in-bhrigu-samhita)

Comment: Soul traverses across births but the soul is covered by vasanas , samskaras and past karma. While the soul itself is pure, the avidya comprising the above three sheaths the atma and causes one to take on various life-forms including, animal and plant. The only way to work towards a "nobler" birth than the current one is to keep karma and vasanas in check through yoga. Yoga is chitta vritti nirodhah - Yoga is the means to stemming the flow of ever-changing thoughts. For it is thoughts that convert to vasanas and samskaras.

Comment: Namaste Animosity of any kind towards any animate or inanimate being, shall result in birth in that "form". Example, a person hating a religion, then at appropriate time destined by God, one shall be born in that religion to defend it !! So hate none, look positiveness in everything, then you shall continue to take birth as a hindu, which has embraced many religioins inspite of other religion's shortcomings. The above is consistent with writings in Upanishad and other exalted saints, sages & yogis of mother India.

Comment: There are some past life regressions which  I have seen went before even this planet existed(Perhaps translated as previous kalpa). Jiva travel through numerous birth of devas,humans, animals,asuras  etc depending on total sanchita karma. Now tell me , in this vast cosmos how we are sure that we were born as hindu?

Answer (score 1):

I see two questions, here the answers for the two.

**it is not necessary for one to be Hindu to be graced and/or blessed by
 God?**

No. God's grace for you is not dependent on the variation in the form, but in the growth of intensity of your Bhakthi. Even within Hinduism, the journey from a Sakaara God, and a belief in many forms of Gods, usually tends to evolve towards one-pointed devotion to a single name and form (such as that of Arunagirinathar or Prahlada) and onwards towards an idea of God that transcends names and forms. The book by Sadhu Om, The Path of Sri Ramana (Part two) illustrates this journey well.

http://www.happinessofbeing.com/path_ramana.html#part_two

**How identities that are derived from social constructs traverse through all of the rebirths :**

In Hinduism, there are three planes of existence, the physical body is only of the gross plane, the other two being sukshma sarira and karana sarira, (subtle form and causal form). The key element that gets carried across births from the actions of a human life, are not the actions themselves, but the subtle impressions you gather from the actions. These are called Vasanas and Samskaras. A subset of these are almost the determinant of the starting point of the next birth, somewhat like the closing balance of your ledger for the current financial year, is the sum of all your transactions in the earlier years.

http://www.sivanandaonline.org/public_html/?cmd=displaysection&section_id=871

> When you are writing a drama, if sleep comes in, you stop writing and
>   retire to bed. As soon as you get up, you continue to write from where
>   you have left the previous night. Even so, when you take up a new
>   incarnation, you begin to continue the work which you had left
>   unfinished in your previous life in accordance with the current of
>   Vasanas of your past life.